# How to change root Docusign account information

Tags: docusignapi

I'd like to change the root of a Docusign Dev account from one person to another but I don't see if and how that's possible.  I could create a new account however since we have envelopes and specific settings in the account, abandoning the current account would be our option of last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms "account" and "user" are sometimes confused.

**For the user:**

1. Log in to the developer account in question.
2. From upper-right menu select "Manage Profile."
3. You'll find the profile page where you can change the email and name.

**For the account:**

1. Log in to the developer account in question.
2. From the top navigation bar select "Settings."
3. From the left menu select "Account Profile."

Comment: Wow - yes, that's very clear now that you made it clear.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Click sign up and log in to your account and then enter your name and email. If that worked and you managed to sign up that’s great. If not, please contact the company.